# Transcode FLAC to FLAC without losing any metadata and replacing source files after validation

Tags: metadata, flac, audio-conversion, verification

I have a fairly large collection of FLAC files which were encoded using a low compression level, and I would like to update them to a better FLAC encoder+compression level. I would like to avoid losing any metadata (including embedded cue sheets, embedded artwork and other things of that nature), as well as automatically replace the source files with the new encodes after it's verified that both files decode exactly the same way. How can I achieve this, preferably without doing every step manually?

Answer (score 0):

I do believe that [cuetools](http://www.cuetools.net/wiki/Main_Page) would handle the transcoding. I know for a fact that it'll copy over the metadata - I've used it to transcode a mysteriously semi-broken flac file that would work on some decoders and not others, and it has an *excellent* validation system (accuraterip or CTDB) that checks disks against a database of hashes for tracks and disks.

The only 'manual' step would be to delete the source files once you are done.

The UI takes a little getting used to, and its a little esoteric, but its should do what you need.

Comment: I want validation of encoded files against source files, not of source files against AccurateRip (although that's good to have too).